# Linux servers Lift and Shift Steps

Tags: linux

In our organization we have planned to lift and shift some Linux servers from one location to another location. Its all SAN connected and volume group created . The SAN team will do the replication from their side. Some servers are having multipath and others are having powerpath configured .I required the steps to be followed at the time of server disconnection and reconnection. Please advice ASAP.

Answer (score 7):

1. Document everything.
2. Move everything.
3. Put everything back together based on `1.`